# Share Salesforce calendar with people not having an account in Salesforce

Tags: calendar, sync

How do I share my calendar in Salesforce with people outside of my organization, who are not present as users in Salesforce. They should be able to view my schedule and events as a calendar view.

Comment: If you are using Outlook, there are many great options out there. If not, you may need to expose a public Site.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Outlook connector](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CDgQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fhelp.salesforce.com%2FHTViewHelpDoc%3Fid%3Doutlookcrm_install.htm%26language%3Den_US&ei=f6C-VICuM4rkat_0gPgE&usg=AFQjCNEwQjWCQ-m799fbLz7r964dOdMf_Q&sig2=_n47DF5mmC95bQPrMD30dQ&bvm=bv.83829542,d.d2s&cad=rja), get all the events in your Outlook calendar than share it with people outside Saleforce.